# Oracle 11g max login fail attempts workaround

Tags: database, performance, oracle11g, database-performance

My problem with database starts with situation where I cant really modify anything in database. My project specialist has limited time to help me. Here is the thing:
My user in Oracle database has older schema than actual production one. My section is working on stable and older version. After every release we are keep getting this issue, that something is set (maybe on Jenkins, maybe not) automatically to update our database to version, which we dont want. We tried to resolve it by changing password to user, but it produce new issue. Automat is trying to log in and when it gets wrong pass error, it is trying again. Oracle 11g has this limit 10 failed login attempts, after which it is locking the whole user account, which we use to connect do db by our application server. 
We can not investigate this by turning on auditing failed logins, because it takes place on database space and our db-guy has not allowed us to do it, because if we exceed the space limit (which is about 11GB) the whole database will be dead (our project is not as important to do it). Another thing is that person who probably set the scripts which are our problem doesnt work anymore here.
Our workaround was to manually unlock account to get the connection by application server, and then wait a few secs to get locked again (but the connection of app server was stable). It is stupid, you must admit and the problem is when the connection drops by any reason - app server will not get it automatically, we have to do it manually which is not a solution. 
I have reconsidered it all again, my db-guy has no time to help me, I have no tools and access rights to investigate where this script or whatever other problem causing thing is beeing executed, so I started to thinking: what if we set limit of failed login attempts to unlimited? Will this decrease the performance of database? Will this generate any special new problems? Maybe the solution would be change the PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME to small value? 
I am asking you to some arguments that I could provide to my db-guy to convince him to use this new workarounds so I can start working again with code and not this database problems.

Comment: How many possible sources for that login exist? You could probably find out what's triggering that by disconnecting Computers if only a few possible sources exist, since you will see a result after mere seconds (the account won't be locked again). IMHO you should get rid of the source of that Problem not try to ignore it. Auditing would be one way, the reasoning of your dba sounds a bit odd, but I don't know about your infrastructure. Anyhow, he should be able to tell you the hostnames or IP's of the computers that use that login - that might help too.

Comment: The problem is that there are about 4 environments on this server, and every one of them could update this database. I cant disconnect them, if I could, I would already do that. They are built by Jenkins, so investigation through IP's simply doesnt give any results